# UVA online judge 3n+1: Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++

Ive been working on this problem for a while but every time I submit it I get the wrong answer, however when I input sample cases I seem to produce the right answer. Could anyone help me out here? 
The problem can be found on this site: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36

The code itself:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

long find_cycle_length(long b)
{
    // Finds the max cycle of b
    long max_cycle = 1;
    while (b != 1)
    {
        if (b % 2 != 0)
        {
            b = (3 * b) + 1;
            ++max_cycle;
        }
        else if (b % 2 == 0)
        {
            b /= 2;
            ++max_cycle;
        }
    }
    return max_cycle;
}
long find_max_cycle(vector <long>& b)
{
    vector <long> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
    {
        long buffer = b[i];
        temp.push_back(find_cycle_length(buffer));
    }
    long max_cycle = *max_element(temp.begin(), temp.end());

    return max_cycle;
}

int main()
{
        long i = 0; // First number
        long j = 0; // Second number
        long size = 0; // Determines the size of the vector buffer
        long counter = 0; // Used to fill buffer
        cin >> i >> j;


        if (j > i) {
            size = (j - i) + 1;
            counter = i;
        }
        else if (i > j) {
            size = (i - j) + 1;
            counter = j;
        }
        else if (i == j)
        {
            size = 1;
            counter = i;
        }

        vector<long> buffer(size); // Used to store all numbers i to j  
        for (int x = 0; x < buffer.size(); ++x) // fill buffer
        {
            buffer[x] = counter;
            ++counter;
        }

        cout << i << " " << j << " " << find_max_cycle(buffer) << endl;

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to read this part: "The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers". There's more than one.

Comment: Your setup is questionable. You can find each max-cycle *per-pair-line*, output, and move to the next line and the next pair. I fail to see the usefulness of `buffer` whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the instructions.  The sample input isn't

```
1 10
```

but

```
1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000
```

You don't have a while loop that lets the user give you more than one line of input -- your program quits after one.  Why don't you make that change -- let the user keep putting in new lines of input till giving you an end-of-file (or -- it works out the same for coding -- accept all lines of input from an input file redirected to standard input) -- and see if you get an OK?

Oh, I see molbdnilo suggested this in the first comment.  Anyway:  he's right.